# Using Python if/then codeblock to determine line segment lengths in ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, spatial-statistics

Can anyone help me create a codeblock using an if/then statement through the Python parser in Field Calculator, to calculate the length of a line segment when the value of a different field is a certain value?

I am trying to calculate percentages of Passing Zones within Undivided 2-Lane State Highways. I have one field `[PassingZoneDesc]` with values `"Both"`, `"Left"`,  `"Right"` and `"None"`. I have added fields for each type of Passing Zone, and would like to create an expression in Field Calculator that goes along the lines of `If [PassingZoneDesc] = "Left" Then [Length_NPZ_Left] = !Shape.Length@Miles! else [Length_NPZ_Left] = 0`.

I understand the above is a messed-up mash of VB Script and Python. Frankly, I am more familiar with VB Script but apparently ArcMap only supports geometry calculations in Field Calculator with Python now (hence the Python length calculation above). I know there are workarounds available, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to calculate the lengths in this manner.

I am not permitted to upload an actual sample of the data, but here is a screenshot of the attribute table and a draft code I was trying to use.

[image]

Comment: You can compute shape length in a separate field and use vb instead of Python.  On the other hand simple summary statistics on passing zone and length will do.

Comment: I certainly could do as you suggested, but was just wondering if it was even possible to calculate the lengths in the way I specified. Ultimately, yes, it is possible to calculate it with one expression in Field Calculator! See below for user answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following codeblock and assignment statement.

Codeblock:

```
def reclass(l, d):
    if (d =="Both"):
        return l
    else:
        return 0
```

Assignment statement:

```
reclass(!Shape.length@Miles!, !PassingZoneDesc!)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression below will do the job:

`!Shape.length@miles! if !PassingZoneDesc! == "Left" else 0`

Comment: With a tiny bit of tweaking, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per some awesome user answers, there are two options for calculating length with an if/then statement using the Python codeblock in Field Calculator. Below are both calculations that worked for me:

```
!Shape.Length@Miles! if !PassingZoneDesc! == "Left" else 0
```

The above one was pasted into the expression line directly (no codeblock needed). The below one utilizes a codeblock and expression.

Codeblock:

```
def reclass(L, d):
    if (d == "Left"):
        return L
    else:
        return 0
```

Expression:

```
reclass(!Shape.Length@Miles!, !PassingZoneDesc!)
```